# rsync with the "--progress" option prints extra garbage information

Tags: rsync, output

when using `rsync` with the `--progress` option, in addition to printing progress, it also prints strange codes `(xfr#1, to-chk=2/4)`, ie:

```
rsync -a --progress --delete src dst
      1,206 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=2/4)
      3,241 100%    3.09MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#2, to-chk=1/4)
        673 100%  657.23kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#3, to-chk=0/4)
```

What do those mean, and how can I disable these?

First of all, this ads no informational value to me and i am not interested in this.

Second, these codes look like some kind of error codes, and I repeatedly am being cofused thinking some error occurred

Can I print progress without the `xfr` info, whatever that means ?

Comment: What are you complaining about... rsync manpage reveals the only purpose of the --progress option the following way : "This gives a bored user something to watch." :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) explains this pretty well, so I'll just reproduce the content here.

> `--progress`
>
> This option tells rsync to print information showing the progress of
> the transfer. This gives a bored user something to watch. Implies
> `--verbose` if it wasn't already specified.
>
> While rsync is transferring a regular file, it updates a progress line
> that looks like this:
>
> ```
> 782448 63% 110.64kB/s 0:00:04
> ```
>
> In this example, the receiver has reconstructed 782448 bytes or 63% of
> the sender's file, which is being reconstructed at a rate of 110.64
> kilobytes per second, and the transfer will finish in 4 seconds if the
> current rate is maintained until the end.
>
> ...
>
> When the file transfer finishes, rsync replaces the progress line with
> a summary line that looks like this:
>
> ```
> 1238099 100% 146.38kB/s 0:00:08 (xfer#5, to-check=169/396)
> ```
>
> In this example, the file was 1238099 bytes long in total, the average
> rate of transfer for the whole file was 146.38 kilobytes per second
> over the 8 seconds that it took to complete, it was the 5th transfer
> of a regular file during the current rsync session, and there are 169
> more files for the receiver to check (to see if they are up-to-date or
> not) remaining out of the 396 total files in the file-list.

---

Judging by your description, you can check if the `-v`/`--verbose` option is sufficient for your needs.

> `-v`, `--verbose`
>
> This option increases the amount of information you are given during
> the transfer. By default, rsync works silently. A single `-v` will give
> you information about what files are being transferred and a brief
> summary at the end. Two `-v` options will give you information on what
> files are being skipped and slightly more information at the end. More
> than two `-v` options should only be used if you are debugging rsync.